How can I change the scrollY when the InfiniteScroll has rendered
in my project I want change the scrollY when user click some button，I tryed change initialScrollY use the useState hooks，but it does not work :(
my code like this
const [initialScrollY, setInitialScrollY] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (searchParams?.get('filter')) {
      setInitialScrollY(300);
    } else {
      setInitialScrollY(0);
    }
  }, [searchParams]);
<InfiniteScroll
          initialScrollY={initialScrollY}
          dataLength={searchList.length}
          next={getSearchListMore}
          hasMore={hasMore}
          loader={<SearchListSkeleton />}
          hasChildren
          scrollableTarget="scrollableDiv"
          className="flex-1 flex-grow overflow-y-scroll no-scrollbar"
          height="calc(100vh - 96px)"
        >
......
</InfiniteScroll>


I have read your code and here are some possibility you should fix for it
1- Use useRef for the scrollable div
2- Use useEffect to update scroll position
3- Ensure the scrollable div has the correct id
Here's some fixes for it
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import InfiniteScroll from 'react-infinite-scroll-component';

const MyComponent = ({ searchParams, searchList, getSearchListMore, hasMore }) => {
  const [initialScrollY, setInitialScrollY] = useState(0);
  const scrollableDivRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (searchParams?.get('filter')) {
      setInitialScrollY(300);
    } else {
      setInitialScrollY(0);
    }
  }, [searchParams]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (scrollableDivRef.current) {
      scrollableDivRef.current.scrollTop = initialScrollY;
    }
  }, [initialScrollY]);

  return (
    <InfiniteScroll
      initialScrollY={initialScrollY}
      dataLength={searchList.length}
      next={getSearchListMore}
      hasMore={hasMore}
      loader={<SearchListSkeleton />}
      scrollableTarget="scrollableDiv"
      className="flex-1 flex-grow overflow-y-scroll no-scrollbar"
      height="calc(100vh - 96px)"
    >
      <div id="scrollableDiv" ref={scrollableDivRef}>
        {/* Your content goes here */}
      </div>
    </InfiniteScroll>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;

if you used this component https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-infinite-scroll-component, please read the docs to how to use it better I guessed that and searched on Google to find your package.
Please.

thank you for your help.   but it still doesn't work，I will try to rebuild the component base on dom scroll api :(

Could you please tell me what was the problem?

the  react-infinite-scroll-component  designed initialScrollY proto just for componnet init stage，so setInitialScrollY(300) will not work

useEffect(() => {
if (scrollableDivRef.current) {
scrollableDivRef.current.scrollTop = initialScrollY;
}
}, [initialScrollY]);   this code can help to scroll，but  not  to reuse the InfiniteScroll  Animation, and the InfiniteScroll seems to be excessive in that case。
